# Oracle: fetch value of columns based on another table column

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have two tables, one of them is a main table and the other is the decode. The decode has 142 rows and 2 columns. Cause of death code and description. The main table has person information and the reason of death and secondary reason of death.

**Decode table**

| code | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | infection |
| 2 | covid |

**main table**

| client | reason_1 | reason_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | null |
| 02 | 2 | 1 |
| 03 | 1 | 2 |

**Expected table**

| client | reason_1 | reason_2 | reason_1_desc | reason_2_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | null | infection | null |
| 02 | 2 | 1 | covid | infection |
| 03 | 1 | 2 | infection | covid |

How can I get this output without typing in all the values from decode table and using decode function or subquery factoring?

Comment: This is just main_table left join decode_table on main_table.reason = decode_table.code

Comment: This will only get values for reason_1 and not reason_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `description` table twice (for each of two reasons):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  t_decode (code, description) as
  3    (select 1, 'infection' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'covid'     from dual
  5    ),
  6  t_main (client, reason, reason_2) as
  7    (select '01', 1, null from dual union all
  8     select '02', 2, 1    from dual union all
  9     select '03', 1, 2    from dual
 10    )
```

Query:

```
 11  select m.client, m.reason, m.reason_2,
 12    d1.description reason_desc,
 13    d2.description reason_2_desc
 14  from t_main m left join t_decode d1 on d1.code = m.reason
 15                left join t_decode d2 on d2.code = m.reason_2
 16  order by m.client;

CL     REASON   REASON_2 REASON_DE REASON_2_
-- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------
01          1            infection
02          2          1 covid     infection
03          1          2 infection covid

SQL>
```